# Как найти определенное изменение с помощью сигнала Django?

Tags: python, django, signal

## Концепция:

Я изменяю определнный `Model`. Затем после сохранения срабатывает `POST_SAVE`-сигнал. (*Все происходит в Djangp-admin*)

## Вопрос:

Как именно мне отследить, что был изменен определенный `Model` и затем запускать функцию?

Comment: Ещё хотелось бы извлечь новое значение (именно у отслеживаемого)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось решить самому. Решил, что нужно после инициализирования сохранить результат таким образом. Поправьте, если что-то не так.

```
@receiver(signal=signals.post_init, sender=AgentCards)
def send_bucks(instance, **kwargs):
    instance.old_bucks = instance.bucks


@receiver(signal=signals.post_save, sender=AgentCards)
def send_bucks(instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.old_bucks != instance.bucks:
        send_message(instance.chat_id, (instance.bucks - instance.old_bucks))
```